# Get current temperature of a city in PHP

Tags: php, api, time, temperature

I am developing a website that needs the current temperature of the city. how can I include the temperature in my PHP page.

Comment: Step 1: get a thermometer... Seriously though: pick one of the many weather APIs out there that you like and query it from PHP.

Comment: you need to use third party api which accepts parameters as location name or lat/long and give you the temperature in some format see http://99webtools.com/Get-weather-information-using-php.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get the weather data in your php application, you need to do a call to an API.
for example this one: 
http://openweathermap.org/current

As shown on the page above, you can request the data by a city name:
In JSON api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

You can access this data by doing something similar to this:

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

$weather = json_decode($json);
$kelvin = $weather->main->temp;
$celcius = $kelvin - 273.15;
?>
```

now $kelvin is the temperature in Kelvin and $celcius in Celcius!

I hope this helps you out a bit, please try to be more specific if this is not what you meant!

Comment: I got an array, how can I get the temperature in degree celcius

Comment: Take any of the `temp` variables and subtract 273.15 (Kelvin -> Celsius)

Comment: I've edited the post for you!

Comment: Thank you Jason. its working very well

Comment: this weather api not accurate for me (LK)

Comment: @devopsEMK can you be more concrete, what's not accurate? You might want to put this in a new Question, because this one is solved :)

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="New Delhi") and u='c'&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys